# Using multilevel modeling to test differences in the ability of trait and state measures to predict outcomes

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, nested-data

I'm currently trying to test whether trait is better at predicting overall/mean job performance than state anxiety and whether state anxiety is better at predicting daily job performance than trait anxiety.

I collected data from an ESM diary study, where participants gave measures of their trait anxiety in a prescreen and then self-reported their state anxiety and their job performance daily for 5 days. I'm planning to grand-mean center the trait measure of anxiety and group-mean/person-mean center the state measure of anxiety and enter them as predictors of daily job performance using multilevel regressions/HLM, but I'm wondering if this would let me test the question I want to test. From what I understand, trait anxiety as a predictor would predict the overall/mean job performance while state anxiety as a predictor would predict daily performance, but I was wondering if anyone knows a way of testing how well state anxiety predicts overall/mean performance and how well trait anxiety predicts daily performance?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting study! Multilevel data and the off-the shelf models we use to analyze them do not allow you to test the questions in your first paragraph. It is of course possible to do so in theory, but I am not aware of any off-the shelf software that would work. Lesa Hoffman has thought a lot about time-varying predictors (see https://www.lesahoffman.com/CLDP945/CLDP945_Lecture09_Multivariate.pdf for a thorough examination).